# Is that good to wrap a sql query to do a row count query

Tags: sql

Given a arbitrary sql query:

```
select foo from bar
```

this sql query can be very complex, then I want to know the record size of this query, so I just wrap it like this:

```
select count(*) from (select foo from bar)  t
```

Should I do it like this? Should I count on some indexed column other than just using `count(*)`

**Edit:**

---

Sorry forget to mention this: **Performance is my main concern**.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not restricted to any specific DBMS

Comment: Well, optimizers between the different DBMS are **very** different. So if the query for one DBMS works fine another optimizer might not be so smart to remove unnecessary stuff.

Comment: and perhaps if later you are going to use both the data and the row count, instead of executing 2 queries, I think it would be good that you only get the data, and in the application level, if you are using Java for example, you can just count it with `resultset.last()` and `resultset.getRow()`

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: Not if you want a paged result, so say for example row 0-50 from a million row table.

Comment: sorry that I didn't include all possible constraints / cases in my one single comment, and thank you, @Patrick Hofman

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: It wasn't to criticize you, just a note when to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

COUNT(*) is the fastest way to count rows, because it does nothing else than that.

If you replace this with COUNT(col), no matter if col is indexed or not, the dbms will have to check each value in col for null, because nulls are not counted. So this cannot be faster then COUNT(*). In case col is not nullable, the dbms may notice this and skip the null test. Then you are back to what COUNT(*) does.

So you would always use COUNT(*). You would only use COUNT(col) when you wanted to count non-null occurences - or COUNT(DISTINCT col) to count distinct values for that matter.

(BTW: Neither would you use COUNT(1), because here you tell the dbms to "create" a 1 per record and test it for null. Well, 1 is never null, so even the simplest dbms usually notices this and skips the null test. But then why not write COUNT(*) in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

Specefic to `SQL Server`: `COUNT` is the only aggregate function that considers `NULL` marks. So if you want to handle only occurrences of known values in `foo` column or any other column in `select` list use `COUNT(COLUMN)` else go for `COUNT(*)`.